# DotNetCore | The 'MySQLNumberTypeMapping' does not support value conversions

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

We are using Entity framework (Code First) to read a Table in MySQL using Asp.NET core, and facing below exception while reading the table:

Error Message:
The 'MySQLNumberTypeMapping' does not support value conversions. Support for value conversions typically requires changes in the database provider.

Query:

```
var existing = (from x in db.loyaltyCards select x).OrderByDescending(x=>x.CardNumber).FirstOfDefault();
```

Comment: Having this same issue when trying to create an update on the database when running 'dot-net ef update'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50643830